# Rolling 12 Month sum in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, date, powerpivot, dax, rolling-sum

In PowerPivot Excel 2016 I write a formula for rolling 12 month sum of sales as below :

```dax
Rolling Sum:=CALCULATE (
[Sales] ,
DATESBETWEEN (
    Sales[Date],
    FIRSTDATE(DATEADD(Sales[Date],-365,DAY)),
    LASTDATE (Sales[Date] )
 )
)
```

But it seems not working correctly. for each month it shows me only sales of that month!
Does anybody knows how should I fix my problem?!

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a [Date/Calendar](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Dates-in-Power-Pivot-1269d71a-6d4e-4ab6-a8a8-d32a82e82f5a) table you can't use [Time Intelligence functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634763.aspx) properly.

Despite the best practice would be have a Calendar/Date table and use Time Intelligence functions, you can get the desired result by using an explicit filter:

```
Rolling Sum :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sales],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Sales ),
        [Date]
            >= MAX ( Sales[Date] ) - 365
            && [Date] <= MAX ( Sales[Date] )
    )
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks again Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

Using fixed 365 days does not properly account for leap days. In the following code, "[CurDatePerCalendar]" measure contains the date for which you want to calculate the average.

```
Sales TTM = 
VAR base = [CurDatePerCalendar]
VAR StartDate = EDATE(base,-12) + 1
VAR EndDate = base
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    [SalesSum],
    FILTER ( _Calendar,
    _Calendar[Date] >= StartDate
    && 
    _Calendar[Date] <= EndDate )
)
```