# How can I calculate a rolling average in DAX/PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

After going through several posts on StackOverflow *and* the PowerBI forums, I still can't figure out how to calculate a rolling average based on a given period- in my case, a 30-day rolling average.

Most of the posts I've seen advocate something either identical or really similar to this:

```
Rolling Sum :=
CALCULATE (
    [Sales],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Sales ),
        [Date]
            >= MAX ( Sales[Date] ) - 365
            && [Date] <= MAX ( Sales[Date] )
    )
)
```

(code taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770792/3856609))

...and yet, I can't seem to get the proper values.

In my case, I have the following:

1. "closing date" for a given loan (column)
2. loan count (measure)
3. closing length (column)- length of time (in days) to close a loan

What I'd like to calculate is the rolling 30 day average for any given day. I coded the following:

```
Rolling Average = 
    CALCULATE (
        SUM(Query1[Closing_Length])/[Loan Count],                                 
        FILTER (
            ALL ( Query1 ),                             
            [Closing Date].[Date]                                  
                >= MAX ( Query1[Closing Date] ) - 30
                && [Closing Date] <= MAX (  Query1[Closing Date] )
        )
    )
```

To check the results, I used a visual filter to examine one month's worth of data and these are the results:

[image]

Note the totals row at the bottom; for this given period, there are 102 loans and it took an aggregate of 3922 days for them to close. The average I'd like to calculate is 3922/102, which should equal approximately 38.45 days. Instead, we see 42.

How can I fix this?

Comment: http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/rolling-12-months-average-in-dax/

Comment: @KrystianSakowski No, that post doesn't apply to a rolling 30 day period. It makes use of the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` function, and for a rolling 30-day period, you can't use a "same period"-anything function for all days without getting errors.

Comment: Could you post expression or data for this member Query1[CTC Days])?

Comment: @KrystianSakowski Sorry, it should have been "Closing_Length"- fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Measure based solution:**

```
Rolling Average Measure =
VAR A =
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Query' ),
            'Query'[Closing Date] <= MAX ( 'Query'[Closing Date] )
        ),
        ROUND ( 'Query'[Closing Length], 2 )
    )
VAR B =
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Query' ),
            'Query'[Closing Date] <= MAX ( 'Query'[Closing Date] )
        ),
        ROUND ( 'Query'[Loan Count], 2 )
    )
RETURN
    A / B
```

**Calculated column based solution:**

```
Rolling Average =
VAR CurrentDate = 'Query'[Closing Date]
VAR T =
    FILTER ( 'Query', [Closing Date] <= CurrentDate )
RETURN
    ROUND ( SUMX ( T, 'Query'[Closing Length] ) / SUMX ( T, [Loan Count] ), 2 )
```

**Print Screen:**
[image: Rolling Average Measure]

Comment: This is really neat, Krystian- thank you. However, after trying to implement both solutions, I've had two issues- for the column-based solution, I have the error `A circular dependency was detected: Query1[Rolling Average].` For the measure-based solution, I simply run out of memory; the visual tries to run for about 5-10 minutes, and then finally shows an error window saying that there's not enough memory to produce what I'm asking it to. 
Any suggestions on how to deal with either?

Comment: Seems that you are doing something wrong. Take a look at my .pbix project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6godtc8h4vre1c7/tst.pbix?dl=0
Furthermore please update PBI to the most recent version.
Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: The one glaring difference I see between our two files is that `Loan Count` is a column on your end, whereas in mine, it's a measure. In my ETL, I have many loan numbers and each loan number with its own closing date;  thus, `Loan Count` is actually a measure set to `COUNT('Query1'[LoanNumber])`. I've tried to make another table with a `Closing Date` column of unique dates, and then another column with the count of all loans associated with that respective closing date. I'm struggling with the latter.